# Как программно менять цвет View и всем дочерним компонентам 14 API

Tags: java, android

Требуется при нажатии на View делать цвет View и дочерних темнее, как при долгом нажатии в lollipop. При повторном долго нажатии, убрать затемнение.

[image: До нажатия] 
[image: После нажатия]

Comment: ripple эффект только с 5+. на 14-19 апи будет просто меняться фон. сразу всей кнопки

Comment: мне не нужен рипл эффект, мне нужно что-то вроде foreground, но он с 23 API